# Why is my camera overexposing every time I use flash?

Tags: nikon, flash, overexposure

No matter what setting I have my camera on, any time I use the flash the exposure goes super high. I try changing my ISO and aperture, too, but it doesn't help. I have a Nikon D3400, could this be a sensor issue? It was working just a few days ago and I picked it up again to find it completely messed up. As long as I don't use the flash it works perfectly, though. What could be wrong?

Comment: What kind of flash are you using? How far away is the camera/flash from the subject?

Comment: Please upload a sample image that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Sounds like the flash might not be compatible with the camera.  What flash are you using?  I had the same problem last month when I tried a 3PP flash unit.

Comment: "exposure goes super high" - please provide actual figures, ISO, aperture, exposure, & a copy of the resulting image.

Comment: If you're using a speedlight, have you checked the flash is seated correctly in the hotshoe so that all the flash foot pins touch all the hotshoe contacts? A TTL flash, if mis-seated will always fire at full power in TTL.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the flash in a non-Auto mode (Aperture or Speed priority) the camera assumes the flash is used for fill-in and computes the exposure for a flash-less photo. So if you subject is dark this will crank up the exposure and then you'll have a big flash added.  So when you use the flash, either go full-manual, or use the "Program" mode of your camera.

Comment: "No matter what setting I have my camera on..." would, to me, indicate M and P modes were used as well, and this isn't the typical defaults-to-fill issue with the priority modes.

Comment: @inkista Yes, but I read this as "No matter what setting **I think about** putting my camera on". And the OP only mentions Aperture and ISO. And the OP didn't contradict me so far:)

Answer (score 0):

I have a d3300 and sometimes I had the same problem.
If you take the photo in almost total darkness the camera can't calculate well which flash output to apply. Also, these cameras have a max shutter speed of 1/200 with flash and it ends in burnt or overexposed photos easily.

Use manual mode for flash, reduce its power and also use smaller apertures.